# Django - Simple search form

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.9 with Python 3.5, I would like to make a simple search form:

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Movie, Genre

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'movies/index.html'
    page_template = 'movies/all_movies.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_movies'
    model = Movie

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'all_genres': Genre.objects.all(),
            'page_title': 'Latest'
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            return Movie.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        else:
            return Movie.objects.all()
```

**form**

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="searchform">
    <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="Search..."/>
</form>
```

For some reason I keep getting the error:

> name 'request' is not defined

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error does not come from your template as you seem to think. It comes from your view

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
```

It should be

```
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
```

Comment: How can I add a validation on the text box? I want to raise a warning if someone clicks on the search button while the textbox is empty.

Comment: `required = True`