# How to create a webpage for searching in a mongoDB database?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, web, database

I have a mongoDB database of products. And I want to build a webpage in which I can search and filter results from the database. Like this one: 
https://demo.getsaleor.com/products/category/groceries-5/
(just this page and not the whole website)

1 - Can I find a template to do this job with minimal changes?

2 - If there is no templates, do you have any idea how to do this in a simple way?

3 - Is Django good for this?

Thank You.

Comment: If your're interested in mongoDB then I would recommend a MEAN stack app , its a lot easier to get setup and its all javascript,  http://mean.io/ ...Another recommendation is Firebase https://firebase.google.com/..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongodb is part of the MEAN stack that is used to build *single page applications* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle) ).  single page apps are currently very favored and it is said that SPAs are 'the future of the internet' however they are more complicated to build than plain html pages ( i think )

when viewing the source
http://demo.getsaleor.com/products/category/groceries-5/ is not a single page app ...

the function you want to reproduce is `<script type="application/ld+json">{"potentialAction": {"@type": "SearchAction", "query-input": "required name=search_term", "target": "http://demo.getsaleor.com//search/?q={search_term}"}, "@type": "WebSite", "@context": "http://schema.org", "name": "Saleor e-commerce", "url": "http://demo.getsaleor.com/", "description": ""}</script>` this is done by sending a json to the server that contains the search string and so searches a database. on serverside you can use django in combination with mongodb for this...

there is a django engine for mongodb : https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html  so django is good with mongodb...

Comment: not exactly like that webpage's code, all I want is to search in mongodb database and filter results

Comment: do not know. if you search for 'mean stack tutorial' or 'django mongodb tutorial' there are ready solutions with source code for querying adatabase...

Comment: I have searched and I didn't found any tutorial about this. Do you know a tutorial about: create a django webpage/website for searching in mongodb database?

Comment: maybe you have to combine tutorials. a tutorial about using mongodb with django is i.e. this http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-django-and-mongodb-build-blog?page=0,1 how to build a website that uses django is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website . the communication between the browser ( frontend-side ) and the django website (backend-side) can i.e. be done by forms ( https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/ ) or by more complicated ajax requests ( https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/ )

Comment: here is an example for a search form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842386/django-simple-search-form

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful